# Understanding relation between Laurent Series and Singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

I am thinking about an example, in order to better understand how Laurent Series help us understand the Poles, Zeros and Essential singularities of a complex function.

I am trying to find the singularities of $\frac{1}{sin(z)} - \frac{1}{z}$

Individually, 1/z has a pole of order 1 at 0

For $\frac{1}{z}$ I am quite confused as to what to do. Given for sin(z), it has zeros at $n \pi$ for all integer $n$, so the inverse has poles of order 1 at those points. But what happens at 0, where $\frac{1}{sin(z)} - \frac{1}{z}$ have poles pushing against each other?

Thank you for some hints on how to see this example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as $\frac {z-\sin\, z}{z\sin \,z}$ and apply L'Hopital's Rule twice to see that the limit as $z \to 0$ is $0$. The function has a removable singularity at $0$.

Comment: Ohhh, it works! But could we see this using Laurent series?

Comment: $\frac z {\sin \, z}$ is analytic near $0$. Its power series expansion (in $|z|<\pi$) is of the form $1+a_1z+\cdots $. Dividing by $z$ you get the Laurent series for $\frac 1 {\sin\, z}$ which is of the form $\frac 1 z+g(z)$ with $g$ analytic.